# Displaying image name below the images in php

Tags: php, css, opendir

This is the code I am using for making a gallery type:

Main PHP :

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'images/'; //image's folder path

$num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{JPG,jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$folder = opendir($folder_path);

if($num_files > 0)
{
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))) 
    {
        $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || 

$extension == 'bmp') 
        {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  

height="200" /></a>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "the folder was empty !";
}
closedir($folder);
```

What should I do to display all image-names. Please help.

Comment: $file is your image name. You can print this below image.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? How to echo a string? Or how to get the "image name"?

Comment: yes how to get the image name?

Comment: @AmitRajput so i just use echo $file???? sorry i'm new to php..

Comment: as @AmitRajput said: `$file` is the only "image name" available.

Comment: @AnishDhoni yes just echo $file.

Comment: @Jeff thanks bro..appreciate your help

Comment: @AmitRajput thanks bro that really solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside `while` loop:

```
$file_path = $folder_path.$file;
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$extension = strtolower($path_parts['extension']);
if($extension=='jpg' || $extension =='png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp')
{
    echo '<a href="'.$file_path.'"><img src="'.$file_path.'" height="200" />'.$path_parts['filename'].'</a>';
}
```

Comment: yes.will try this and let u know.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome :) if it helps you, accept/up-vote my answer :) @AnishDhoni

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
$file_path = $folder_path.$file;
```

here `$file` is the name of the file, you can use this to display the file name like:

```
echo $file;
```

As per your requirement it is like:

```
<a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"
<?php echo $file; ?>
```

Comment: Just another help how do i make it properly aligned with the image so that it is just below it not to its right or anywhere else..

Comment: <p><?php echo $file; ?></p> it will show the image name on next line. Use some css to align it where you want.

Comment: so i was wondering whether u can help me with one more problem. i've included submit button below images.now i want that it should send that image to my email..can i do that???

Comment: @AnishDhoni *"i've included submit button below images.now i want that it should send that image to my email..can i do that???"* - that's another question entirely; post a new question for it.